# How to rotate a image without losing the edges

Tags: math, opencv, rotation, javacv

i want to rotate some images with variable angle(like 22°) in JavaCV/OpenCV.
At the moment i use  `cvWarpAffine()`.

My problem is, that i lose the edges of the image after rotating, so i must make the dst.image larger and  move the point of center. On [this page](http://actionscripthowto.com/bounding-box-of-a-rotated-rectangle/) i found some AS-Code to calculate the new size of the image. But i don't know how to realize it with JavaCV/OpenCV

In time i have the following code:

```java
public CvMat rotateImage(int angle) {
    CvPoint2D32f center = new CvPoint2D32f(input.cols() / 2.0F,
            input.rows() / 2.0F);

    CvMat rotMat = cvCreateMat(2, 3, CV_32F);
    cv2DRotationMatrix(center, angle, 1, rotMat);
    CvMat dst = cvCreateMat(input.rows(), input.cols(), input.type());
    cvWarpAffine(input, dst, rotMat);
    return dst;

}
```

Has someone an idea?

Greetings

**//Update**

I don't know...something getting wrong.
If i computed the rotaded image, my result have the right dimension, but it ia mostly black (0 and 360° works)...
here is the code:

```java
public CvMat rotateImage(float angle) {
    CvPoint2D32f center = new CvPoint2D32f(input.cols() / 2.0F,
            input.rows() / 2.0F);
    CvBox2D box = new CvBox2D(center, cvSize2D32f(input.cols() - 1,
            input.rows() - 1), angle);
    CvPoint2D32f points = new CvPoint2D32f(4);
    cvBoxPoints(box, points);
    CvMat pointMat = cvCreateMat(1, 4, CV_32FC2);
    pointMat.put(0, 0, 0, points.position(0).x());
    pointMat.put(0, 0, 1, points.position(0).y());
    pointMat.put(0, 1, 0, points.position(1).x());
    pointMat.put(0, 1, 1, points.position(1).y());
    pointMat.put(0, 2, 0, points.position(2).x());
    pointMat.put(0, 2, 1, points.position(2).y());
    pointMat.put(0, 3, 0, points.position(3).x());
    pointMat.put(0, 3, 1, points.position(3).y());
    CvRect boundingRect = cvBoundingRect(pointMat, 0);

    CvMat dst = cvCreateMat(boundingRect.height(), boundingRect.width(),
            input.type());

    CvPoint2D32f centerDst = new CvPoint2D32f(center.x()
            + (dst.cols() / 2.0F), center.y() + (dst.rows() / 2.0F));

    CvMat rotMat = cvCreateMat(2, 3, CV_32F);
    cv2DRotationMatrix(centerDst, angle, 1, rotMat);
    CvMat trans = cvCreateMat(3, 3, CV_32F);
    cvZero(trans);
    trans.put(0, 2, dst.cols() / 2.0F);
    trans.put(1, 2, dst.rows() / 2.0F);

    trans.put(0, 0, 1);
    trans.put(1, 1, 1);
    trans.put(2, 2, 1);

    CvMat newRot = cvCreateMat(3, 3, CV_32F);
    cvZero(newRot);
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            newRot.put(i, j, rotMat.get(i, j));
        }
    }

    newRot.put(2, 2, 1);
    cvMul(trans, newRot, newRot, 1);

    cvWarpPerspective(input, dst, newRot);
    // cvWarpAffine(input, dst, dstRotMat);

    return dst;

}
```

The `rotMat` looks like:

```
[ 0.9396926, 0.34202015, -311.1334
 -0.34202015, 0.9396926, 601.47485 ]
```

The `trans` (the org. picture have a size of 1428x928px):

```
[ 1.0, 0.0, 836.0
0.0, 1.0, 699.0
0.0, 0.0, 1.0 ]
```

and the `newRot`

```
[ 0.9396926, 0.0, -260107.52
-0.0, 0.9396926, 420430.94
0.0, 0.0, 1.0 ]
```

i can't find the mistake

**//Update 2**

```java
public CvMat rotateImage(float angle) {
    CvPoint2D32f center = new CvPoint2D32f(input.cols() / 2.0F,
            input.rows() / 2.0F);
    CvBox2D box = new CvBox2D(center, cvSize2D32f(input.cols() - 1,
            input.rows() - 1), angle);
    CvPoint2D32f points = new CvPoint2D32f(4);
    cvBoxPoints(box, points);
    CvMat pointMat = cvCreateMat(1, 4, CV_32FC2);
    pointMat.put(0, 0, 0, points.position(0).x());
    pointMat.put(0, 0, 1, points.position(0).y());
    pointMat.put(0, 1, 0, points.position(1).x());
    pointMat.put(0, 1, 1, points.position(1).y());
    pointMat.put(0, 2, 0, points.position(2).x());
    pointMat.put(0, 2, 1, points.position(2).y());
    pointMat.put(0, 3, 0, points.position(3).x());
    pointMat.put(0, 3, 1, points.position(3).y());
    CvRect boundingRect = cvBoundingRect(pointMat, 0);

    CvMat dst = cvCreateMat(boundingRect.height(), boundingRect.width(),
            input.type());

    // CvPoint2D32f centerDst = new CvPoint2D32f(((dst.cols()-input.cols()
    // )/ 2.0F),(( dst.rows()-input.rows()) / 2.0F));

    CvMat rotMat = cvCreateMat(2, 3, CV_32F);
    cv2DRotationMatrix(center, angle, 1, rotMat);
    CvMat trans = cvCreateMat(3, 3, CV_32F);
    cvZero(trans);
    trans.put(0, 2, (dst.cols() - input.cols()) / 2.0F);
    trans.put(1, 2, (dst.rows() - input.rows()) / 2.0F);

    trans.put(0, 0, 1);
    trans.put(1, 1, 1);
    trans.put(2, 2, 1);

    CvMat newRot = cvCreateMat(3, 3, CV_32F);
    cvZero(newRot);
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            newRot.put(i, j, rotMat.get(i, j));
        }
    }

    newRot.put(2, 2, 1);
    cvMul(trans, newRot, newRot, 1);

    cvWarpPerspective(input, dst, newRot);
    // cvWarpAffine(input, dst, rotMat);

    System.out.println(rotMat);
    System.out.println(trans);
    System.out.println(newRot);

    return dst;
```

At 1 degree the matrix look like:

`rotMat`:

```
 [ 0.9998477, 0.017452406, -8.338219
 -0.017452406, 0.9998477, 12.534734 ]
```

`trans`

```
 [ 1.0, 0.0, -8.0
  0.0, 1.0, -12.0
  0.0, 0.0, 1.0 ]
```

`newRot`

```
 [ 0.9998477, 0.0, 66.70575
   -0.0, 0.9998477, -150.41681
   0.0, 0.0, 1.0 ]
```

**FINAL**

Working JavaCode of the instruction from Hammer:

```java
public CvMat rotateImage(float angle) {
    CvPoint2D32f center = new CvPoint2D32f(input.cols() / 2.0F,
            input.rows() / 2.0F);
    CvBox2D box = new CvBox2D(center, cvSize2D32f(input.cols() - 1,
            input.rows() - 1), angle);
    CvPoint2D32f points = new CvPoint2D32f(4);
    cvBoxPoints(box, points);
    CvMat pointMat = cvCreateMat(1, 4, CV_32FC2);
    pointMat.put(0, 0, 0, points.position(0).x());
    pointMat.put(0, 0, 1, points.position(0).y());
    pointMat.put(0, 1, 0, points.position(1).x());
    pointMat.put(0, 1, 1, points.position(1).y());
    pointMat.put(0, 2, 0, points.position(2).x());
    pointMat.put(0, 2, 1, points.position(2).y());
    pointMat.put(0, 3, 0, points.position(3).x());
    pointMat.put(0, 3, 1, points.position(3).y());
    CvRect boundingRect = cvBoundingRect(pointMat, 0);

    CvMat dst = cvCreateMat(boundingRect.height(), boundingRect.width(),
            input.type());

    CvMat rotMat = cvCreateMat(2, 3, CV_32FC1);
    cv2DRotationMatrix(center, angle, 1, rotMat);

    double y_1 = ((boundingRect.width() - input.cols()) / 2.0F)
            + rotMat.get(0, 2);
    double y_2 = ((boundingRect.height() - input.rows()) / 2.0F + rotMat
            .get(1, 2));

    rotMat.put(0, 2, y_1);
    rotMat.put(1, 2, y_2);

    cvWarpAffine(input, dst, rotMat);

    return dst;

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

opencv has a function already for finding a bounding rectangle which is what the code you linked to is doing.  Here is an example of using it

```
std::vector<cv::Point2f> points;
points.push_back(cv::Point2f(0,0));
points.push_back(cv::Point2f(13,0));
points.push_back(cv::Point2f(0,11));
points.push_back(cv::Point2f(10,10));


cv::Rect rectangle = cv::boundingRect(points);
```

The returned rectangle will have its top left corner at (0,0), a width of 14 and a height of 12, the smallest dimensions which will contain every point.  The steps you need are as follows

1. Get coordinates for all 4 corners of your image.
2. Transform each of those coordinates by your affine transform.
3. Pass those points into cv::boundingRect to get the bounding rectangle.

The dimensions of the rectangle returned by boundingRect are the dimensions your destination image needs.  Do not consider the location of the bounding rectangle, only its dimensions.

**Edit**

The second problem is to align the center of your old image with the center of the new image.  If the dimensions of a rectangle change by dw and dh then

```
centerNew.x = centerOld.x+dw/2;
centerNew.y = centerOld.y+dh/2;
```

So you need the entire old image to move right by dw/2 and down (positive y) dh/2.  This movement can be wrapped into your affine transform.  You want each pixel to be warped by the transform and then translated by the matrix

```
tran_mat = [1,0,dw/2,
            0,1,dh/2]
```

To combine the two they need to be multiplied together

NewWarp = tran_mat*old_warp;

Unfortunately you cannot just multiply them because their dimensions do not match.  In that case, convert them both to 3x3 matrices by adding [0,0,1] as a new third row.  Then they can be multiplied together.  You can then pass that matrix into cv::warpPerspective or convert it back to an affine transform by dropping the bottom row (which should still be [0,0,1].

**Edit 2**
I think you have two problems.  First

```
cv2DRotationMatrix(centerDst, angle, 1, rotMat);
```

centerDst should represent the center of the input image, which should be

```
CvPoint2D32f center = new CvPoint2D32f(input.cols() / 2.0F,input.rows() / 2.0F);
```

so change your call to

```
cv2DRotationMatrix(center, angle, 1, rotMat);
```

Also, the variables put in the translation matrix need to be the distance between the center of image1 and the center of image 2.  There are a few ways of calculating that but

```
trans.put(0, 2, dst.cols() / 2.0F);
trans.put(1, 2, dst.rows() / 2.0F);
```

is not one of them.  This will give you the movement of the center

```
trans.put(0, 2, (dst.cols()-input.cols()) / 2.0F);
trans.put(1, 2, (dst.rows()-input.rows()) / 2.0F);
```

I would imagine most of the screen was black because you were translating the entire image off the screen.

**Edit3**

I just wrote it myself and tested it.  Here is my code.  There is probably a much more elegant way of doing this without all the conversions from Matx to pt and back but this works for me.  It is using c++ but it still shows the process clearly.  Just figure out where you deviate from this

```
cv::Mat im; //your image
cv::Matx23d rot = getRotationMatrix2D(cv::Point2f(im.cols/2,im.rows/2),45,1);
cv::Matx31d tl(0,0,1);
cv::Matx31d tr(im.cols,0,1);
cv::Matx31d bl(0,im.rows,1);
cv::Matx31d br(im.cols,im.rows,1);

std::vector<cv::Point2f> pts;
cv::Matx21d tl2 = rot*tl;
cv::Matx21d tr2 = rot*tr;
cv::Matx21d bl2 = rot*bl;
cv::Matx21d br2 = rot*br;
pts.push_back(cv::Point2f(tl2(0),tl2(1)));
pts.push_back(cv::Point2f(tr2(0),tr2(1)));
pts.push_back(cv::Point2f(bl2(0),bl2(1)));
pts.push_back(cv::Point2f(br2(0),br2(1)));

cv::Rect bounds = cv::boundingRect(pts);

cv::Matx33d tran(1,0,(bounds.width-im.cols)/2,
                 0,1,(bounds.height-im.rows)/2,
                 0,0,1);
cv::Matx33d rot33;
for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    rot33(i) = rot(i);
rot33(2,0) = 0;
rot33(2,1) = 0;
rot33(2,2) = 1;
cv::Matx33d combined = tran*rot33;
cv::Matx23d final;
for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    final(i) = combined(i);

cv::Size im_size(bounds.width,bounds.height);
cv::warpAffine(im, drawing_image,final, im_size);
```

**Edit4**

```
rotation = 45 deg;
width = 300 height = 287

rotation matrix
[0.7071067811865476, 0.7071067811865475, -57.18228688765842;
 -0.7071067811865475, 0.7071067811865476, 147.9497474683058]

translation matrix
[1, 0, 58;
 0, 1, 64;
 0, 0, 1]

combined matrix
[0.7071067811865476, 0.7071067811865475, 0.8177131123415791;
-0.7071067811865475, 0.7071067811865476, 211.9497474683058]
```

Here is the original image

[image: Original Image]

and here it is rotated by 45 deg using the code I posted as is.

[image: Image at 45 deg]

Comment: okay, now i have the size of the dst.image. But it's cropped, too. Because the image doesn't put on center of the dst.image. Is there a way?

Comment: But if (0,0)-(1,1) is zero than alpha and beta get's lost, isn't it?

Comment: @destiny Yes you are completely right, I made a mistake writing the translation matrix.  See the revised matrix.

Comment: hey, thanks. Now i've get a result for 0 and 360 degree (:-X) but all other...somewhere i have made a mistake but i can't find it :/

Comment: mhnm i test it, but it doesn't work, too. If i select 1 degree, the picture where cut on top right (maybe 10% of the image is cut). I update the code a second time.

Comment: thanks for you effort! :) I can't find my mistake. I think both code do the same thing. Can you post your trans and combined matrix please? (and maybe the size of the test picture?) thanks

Comment: @destiny if your code did the same thing as mine it would work :)  See updated answer.

Comment: hehe...okay,thx! now i calculate my matrix by hand and it works....don't know why cvMul produce some rubbish.

Comment: @destiny that is very strange.  If it really does not work in a specific test case perhaps you should ask a SO question about that specifically

Answer (score 0):

The answer by Hammer did the trick for me. It gave an error though. Just needed to change the syntax a bit. This is the function which worked for me.

```
Mat rotateImage(Mat im, double angle){
cv::Matx23d rot = getRotationMatrix2D(cv::Point2f(im.cols/2,im.rows/2),angle,1);
cv::Matx31d tl(0,0,1);
cv::Matx31d tr(im.cols,0,1);
cv::Matx31d bl(0,im.rows,1);
cv::Matx31d br(im.cols,im.rows,1);

std::vector<cv::Point2f> pts;
cv::Matx21d tl2 = rot*tl;
cv::Matx21d tr2 = rot*tr;
cv::Matx21d bl2 = rot*bl;
cv::Matx21d br2 = rot*br;
pts.push_back(cv::Point2f(tl2(0),tl2(1)));
pts.push_back(cv::Point2f(tr2(0),tr2(1)));
pts.push_back(cv::Point2f(bl2(0),bl2(1)));
pts.push_back(cv::Point2f(br2(0),br2(1)));

cv::Rect bounds = cv::boundingRect(pts);

cv::Matx33d tran(1,0,(bounds.width-im.cols)/2,0,1,(bounds.height-im.rows)/2,0,0,1);
cv::Matx33d rot33;
for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    for(int j=0; j<3; j++)
        rot33(i,j) = rot(i,j);

rot33(2,0) = 0;
rot33(2,1) = 0;
rot33(2,2) = 1;
cv::Matx33d combined = tran*rot33;
cv::Matx23d finall;
for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    for(int j=0; j<3; j++)
        finall(i,j) = combined(i,j);

cv::Size im_size(bounds.width,bounds.height);
Mat drawing_image;
cv::warpAffine(im, drawing_image,finall, im_size);

return drawing_image;
}
```